# Magento 2: After migration, I get "No such entity with cartId" on old orders

Tags: magento2, orders, error, migration, no-such-entity-exception

I migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2.3

My site has multiple websites and stores.

But now when I go to old orders in the admin panel and want to add a note to an order I get the error:

```
No such entity with cartId = XXXX
```

This is regarding whether I chose the option `Notify Customer by Email` or not. But if I click on send email, the email is not sent and gives me the same error anyways.

I don't have anything on my logs so I am not sure what is happening.

Note: If I do the same process but for newer orders (orders that were made after the migration), there is no error at all. All running fine.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: check the `store` table and see which store_id for admin store

Comment: Hi @JigsParmar , store_id is 0 for admin store. Does this have anything to do with that? Thanks

Comment: which magento2 version are you using?

Comment: @JigsParmar Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Answer (score 0):

take **db backup** and run the following **sql queries**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

DONT forgot to take **DB backup**